# Struggling To Build Gitea on windows

Tags: windows, bash, go, gitea

I'm Thomas. I have a problem...
so I've never coded in go before, but the more I see the more I like it.

Hehe so I was a little hasty when I posted this please excuse the bad format.

I am new to go so I was not to sure how the install worked, after copying the required files I have managed to get Gitea up and running.

Thanks for the help... Thanks to Gitea and Golang...

```
2019/04/04 15:39:03 routers/init.go:69:GlobalInit() [T] AppPath: C:/Users/Thomas/go/bin/gitea.exe
2019/04/04 15:39:03 routers/init.go:70:GlobalInit() [T] AppWorkPath: C:/Users/Thomas/go/bin
2019/04/04 15:39:03 routers/init.go:71:GlobalInit() [T] Custom path: C:/Users/Thomas/go/bin/custom
2019/04/04 15:39:03 routers/init.go:72:GlobalInit() [T] Log path: C:/Users/Thomas/go/bin/log
2019/04/04 15:39:03 ...dules/setting/log.go:225:newLogService() [I] Gitea v1.9.0-dev built with go1.12.1
2019/04/04 15:39:03 ...dules/setting/log.go:265:newLogService() [I] Gitea Log Mode: Console(Console:info)
2019/04/04 15:39:03 ...les/setting/cache.go:42:newCacheService() [I] Cache Service Enabled
2019/04/04 15:39:03 ...s/setting/session.go:34:newSessionService() [I] Session Service Enabled
2019/04/04 15:39:03 routers/init.go:37:checkRunMode() [I] Run Mode: Development
panic: fail to set message file(en-US): open conf/locale/locale_en-US.ini: The system cannot find the path specified.

goroutine 1 [running]:
code.gitea.io/gitea/vendor/github.com/go-macaron/i18n.initLocales(0xc0001a0755, 0x0, 0x163622a, 0xb, 0xc0001717a0, 0x1644590, 0x12, 0xc0001ca160, 0x16, 0x16, ...)
        C:/Users/Thomas/go/src/code.gitea.io/gitea/vendor/github.com/go-macaron/i18n/i18n.go:57 +0x6f6
code.gitea.io/gitea/vendor/github.com/go-macaron/i18n.I18n(0xc00006c0c0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Thomas/go/src/code.gitea.io/gitea/vendor/github.com/go-macaron/i18n/i18n.go:158 +0xf4
code.gitea.io/gitea/routers/routes.NewMacaron(0xc000285040)
        C:/Users/Thomas/go/src/code.gitea.io/gitea/routers/routes/routes.go:165 +0x869
code.gitea.io/gitea/cmd.runWeb(0xc000285040, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Thomas/go/src/code.gitea.io/gitea/cmd/web.go:125 +0xb5
code.gitea.io/gitea/vendor/github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction(0x1418fa0, 0x1695ed0, 0xc000285040, 0xc00006e8a0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Thomas/go/src/code.gitea.io/gitea/vendor/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:471 +0xb4
code.gitea.io/gitea/vendor/github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run(0xc0001684e0, 0xc000078170, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Thomas/go/src/code.gitea.io/gitea/vendor/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:246 +0x57b
main.main()
        C:/Users/Thomas/go/src/code.gitea.io/gitea/main.go:60 +0x42d

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome! I'm afraid your question is Kind of "not a question". You just dumped some Code and are rather unprecise on what you want to achieve. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. Keep in mind: If you don't think it is worth to invest some time into creating a good question, why should we invest time to create a good answer?

Comment: This does not look like a build error but like a runtime error because you are missing a file `conf/locale/locale_en-US.ini`. Make sure to have this file with proper content.

Comment: Thanks that helped.... sorry i'm new to go :) .

Comment: although : html/template: "home" is undefined

Comment: Wait I got this ... hehe Thanks guys...

Answer (score 0):

```
MichaelA:
welcome! I'm afraid your question is Kind of "not a question".
You just dumped some Code and are rather unprecise on what you want to achieve.
Please have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. 
Keep in mind: If you don't think it is worth to invest some time into creating a 
good question, why should we invest time to create a good answer?
```

```
Volker :
This does not look like a build error but like a runtime error because you are 
missing a file conf/locale/locale_en-US.ini. Make sure to have this file with 
proper content.
```

Thanks!